# Time Machine Backup Hangs on Catalina

Tags: backup, time-machine

I have a 2015, 15 inch MacBook Pro running Catalina and am trying to use Time Machine to backup this computer to a Samsung Portable SSD T7 TOUCH USB 3.2 1TB external hard drive.

However, every time I try this the backup gets stuck in the **"preparing backup"** stage. I already tried deleting an `.inProgress` file, canceling the backup, and restarting it again and that didn't work. I successfully did one backup when I first got the external hard drive.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: How do you define sticking? Doesn‘t happen for a long time?

Comment: SwissCodeMen, when I've waited for a few hours my Mac doesn't progress past the "preparing backup" stage. I even left he machine on over night and it still didn't progress past this stage. 

I just checked my Mac and it has 61.54 GB of 250.79 GB available in storage on my Mac's hard drive. So apparently 189.27 GB of storage is used up. This info might be useful.

Comment: If you have no other data on the external drive, I'd wipe it, reformat it, and begin anew.

Comment: DavidSupportsMonica I have another backup on the external hard drive so I don't want to wipe it.